# Multiple OpenJDK platform binary in Open With menu on windows

Tags: java

I've just fixed my jar association so that my OpenJDK platform binary I could select in the open file with menu actually runs the jar program I've been trying to run. Actually only one of the multiple OpenJDK platform binaries makes the programm run, which makes me think they are all for different java versions but than I can't see the java version they run. I'm new to this so if anyone can explain me why there is multiple OpenJDK platform binaries or why where are that would be much appreciated. [image: Multiple OpenJDK platform binaries in windows file explorer open width function] There is also a 3rd one but it is a lot further down

I searched for answers to this problem for quite a bit and found only a screenshot of someone else on I think macOS who had a java version next to the OpenJDK system libraries, but I cannot find the post on which the screenshot was anymore.